# How to derive the formula for present values and future values of constant cash flow at fixed interest rate?

Tags: proof-explanation

I'm not sure how can the following formula be derived. Please explain step by step with reasons:

Present value of constant cashflow at fixed rate:
[image]

Future value of constant cashflow at fixed rate:
[image]

Comment: sister post to https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/75837/how-to-derive-the-formula-for-present-values-and-future-values-of-constant-cash which is forcibly closed.

Comment: The one cash flow at year $k$ has a present value of $C_t (1+i)^{-k}$. Adding the present values of $t$ upcoming cash flows would be a sum of geometric sequence.

Comment: @peterwhy, sorry, it still doesn't seem very obvious to me. Would you mind deriving it in full as the solution below? Thank you very much.